# How to change 502 error page running NGINX

Tags: nginx, root, bad-gateway

I would like to change my 502 error page to a custom design but I cant find in my server root which Linux distribution is installed, therefore where do I find the original 502 error page.

If this information helps PHP engine in use is NGINX and also Plesk is used as hosting management environment.

Each tutorial points to a different location within server root.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be different depending on Linux distribution,
in Debian 9 the default error page is in `/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html`.

You can also change with the `error_page` directive.

For more details, See:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Comment: Yup, its not there :) I got as far as /usr/share/ but nginx folder was not there. How do I find out which Linux my server runs, that could be a clue where to look for the 502 document.

Comment: What Linux distribution and version are you using?

Comment: I dont know how to find out, from within root :)

Comment: Check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35183/how-do-i-identify-which-linux-distro-is-running